# When moving a group of vertices', how do select a specific one to act as origin when snapping to grid?

Tags: vertices

I am creating a piece of trim and  I have used sheer and now have a line of vertices at a 45-degree angle. when I move the selection of vertices along the Z axis, it chooses some origin point to use when grid snapping absolute.

How can I set that origin point to one of the vertices of my choosing?

I have attached a picture I would like to set the snapping point to the vertices circled in red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try Shift-clicking the vertex you want to use as the origin _twice_ so that it becomes the hilighted one and then doing your snap.

Comment: (with the settings: Snap To : Grid (Absolute) and Snap With: Active)

Comment: @RobinBetts Agreed, but I think that was mentioned in the question so I didn't bother to mention it! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason   I don't know whether it's just my system, though.. Edit Mode snap vertex to absolute grid is a pig. It just won't  do it. I wind up  duping a vertex to snap to, instead.  I should really report it, but I haven't heard anyone else complain, so keep thinking it might be me.

Comment: @RobinBetts It works correctly for me both in 3.6.5 and 4.00 beta both with and without absolute grid snap checked.

Answer (score 0):

all I have figured out a solution, I set the origin of the object and set the 3d cursor position BEFORE using the sheer tool, and the 45 started from the vertex. I still can’t move them as a group with one as defence but I found a solution for now!